# Grails 3 - Restrict html templates to logged in users

Tags: angularjs, templates, grails, asset-pipeline

I am using Grails 3.1.4 together with AngularJS.
Certain sections on the page are for logged in users only and I want to restrict access to the according html templates, so only they can access them.

I have set up the Spring Security so that access to those templates is restricted.
The problem I encounter is, that it appears that all the html templates are loaded when the page is loaded the first time. At that moment the user is not logged in, thus the server returns a 401 error.
Once the users is logged in and tries to navigate to the restricted page, angular checks the template cache, realizes nothing is there and returns a 404 error.

When I look at the index.html in the developer tools, I can see, that the asset pipeline includes a script tag for each template, so all the templates are loaded at the initial page load.
Is it somehow possible, to have the templates loaded and cached dynamically when they are needed for the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might allow HTML templates to be accessible to all. For restricting the content, you might need to implement Spring Security token based Authentication and check accordingly what content should be visible to whom.
Reference : http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/2.0.0.M2/docs/index.html